# MissingMethodException when accessing SignalR IHubContext.Clients in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: signalr, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile Services project which works fine locally but when I Publish it to Azure any attempt to call a method on the client results in:

`System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.IHubConnectionContext Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext.get_Clients()'`

For example:

`_hubContext.Clients.Clients(connectionIds).ClientMethod(true)`

where `_hubContext` was set to `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>()`.
(Note that the same thing happens when `_hubContext` is set to `Services.GetRealtime<MyHub>()` where `Services` is a public property of type 'ApiServices' which has been injected).

I am using the 2.0.3 version of the SignalR.Core from Nuget rather than the latest as the latest is not currently supported by Azure Mobile Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to Nuget giving me the wrong version of the SignalR client for the SignalR server in Azure Mobile.